Dedekind zeta function of abelian number fields is a product of Dirichlet L-functions
Can somebody give an explicit (and self-contained) proof of the fact that the Dedekind zeta function of an abelian number field $K$ is a product of Dirichlet L-functions? I.e.,
$$
\zeta_K(s)=\prod_{\chi\in X}L(s,\chi),
$$
where $X$ is some set of (primitive) Dirichlet characters. Please feel free to assume the Kronecker-Weber Theorem.
This book by Cohen contains the statement of this fact in Theorem 10.5.25, without a proof. The author suggests that the proposition can be proved in the same way as in Theorem 10.5.22, which assumed the functional equation of $\zeta_K$.
A more elementary proof was given here (see the referred book by Washington). But the author's convention on Dirichlet characters makes me very confused: all Dirichlet characters are assumed to be primitive, and the author's usage of the phrase "group of Dirichlet characters associated to a field $K$" is a little confusing to me.
Hence it would be very helpful someone could provide a more self-contained proof of this fact. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The upshot is how Artin L-functions behave under induction and decomposition of representation. Those can be proved by checking local factors directly. There's probably more standard reference for this, but see e.g. https://math.berkeley.edu/~fengt/263C.pdf p.43 for formal properties and p.44 for Example 6.2.5

Have you tried Neukirch?

@dummy I do know how Artin L-functions behave with respect to induced representations. However I'm not sure whether that would allow one to prove the above fact directly. Indeed, if we embed $K\subset\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, then shouldn't we obtain a factorization of the Dedekind zeta function of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ instead of $K$?

@Kimball It seems that proposition (5.12) in Chapter VII proves a fact similar to the one stated above, but not quite the same.

You don't need to embed $K \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Dedekind zeta function of $K$ equals the Artin $L$-function for regular representation of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$. If $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian, the regular representation can be decomposed into sum of characters, and the desired decomposition of $L$-function follows (if necessary, it's in this step that you lift a character of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ to that of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$ using Kronecker-Weber, so you can regard the $L$-function of character of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ as Dirichlet $L$-function).

@dummy I see. Thank you for the clarifications. For those who might see this post later, this is proposition 10.4 in Neukirch.
